# Bash: Trying to append to a variable name in the output of a function

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

this is my very first post on Stackoverflow, and I should probably point out that I am EXTREMELY new to a lot of programming. I'm currently a postgraduate student doing projects involving a lot of coding in various programs, everything from LaTeX to bash, MATLAB etc etc.

If you could explicitly explain your answers that would be much appreciated as I'm trying to learn as I go. I apologise if there is an answer else where that does what I'm trying to do, but I have spent a couple of days looking now.

So to the problem I'm trying to solve: I'm currently using a selection of bioinformatics tools to analyse a range of genomes, and I'm trying to somewhat automate the process.

I have a few sequences with names that look like this for instance (all contained in folders of their own currently as paired files):

```
SOL2511_S5_L001_R1_001.fastq
SOL2511_S5_L001_R2_001.fastq
SOL2510_S4_L001_R1_001.fastq
SOL2510_S4_L001_R2_001.fastq
```

...and so on...

I basically wish to automate the process by turning these in to variables and passing these variables to each of the programs I use in turn. So for example my idea thus far was to assign them as wildcards, using the R1 and R2 (which appears in all the file names, as they represent each strand of DNA) as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

seq1=*R1_001*
seq2=*R2_001*
```

On a rudimentary level this works, as it returns the correct files, so now I pass these  variables to my first function which trims the DNA sequences down by a specified amount, like so:

```
# seqtk is the program suite, trimfq is a function within it, 
# and the options -b -e specify how many bases to trim from the beginning and end of     
# the DNA sequence respectively. 

seqtk trimfq -b 10 -e 20 $seq1 > 
seqtk trimfq -b 10 -e 20 $seq2 >
```

**So now my problem is I wish to be able to append something like "_trim" to the output file which appears after the >, but I can't find anything that seems like it will work online.**

Alternatively, I've been hunting for a script that will take the name of the folder that the files are in, and create a variable for the folder name which I can then give to the functions in question so that all the output files are named correctly for use later on.

Many thanks in advance for any help, and I apologise that this isn't really much of a minimum working example to go on, as I'm only just getting going on all this stuff!

Joe

**EDIT**

So I modified @ghoti 's for loop (does the job wonderfully I might add, rep for you :D ) and now I append trim_, as the loop as it was before ended up giving me a .fastq.trim which will cause errors later.

Is there any way I can append _trim to the end of the filename, but before the extension?

Comment: The alternatively paragraph is another question...
It should be in bash or can be in other languages?

Comment: Yeah I thought it might be different enough to require a new thread, but I figured I'd try and cross one hurdle at a time :)

Bash is all I'm really familiar with at the moment, so that would be prefereable.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want your output files to look like `SOL2510_S4_L001_R2_001_trim.fastq`?  If so, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit is usually better than implied, when matching filenames.  Your wildcards may match more than you expect, especially if you have versions of the files with "_trim" appended to the end!

I would be more precise with the wildcards, and use for loops to process the files instead of relying on `seqtk` to handle multiple files.  That way, you can do your own processing on the filenames.

Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define an array of sequences
sequences=(R1_001 R2_001)

# Step through the array...
for seq in ${sequences[@]}; do

  # Step through the files in this sequence...
  for file in SOL*_${seq}.fastq; do
    seqtk trimfq -b 10 -e 20 "$file" > "${file}.trim"
  done

done
```

I don't know how your folders are set up, so I haven't addressed that in this script.  But the basic idea is that if you want the script to be able to manipulate individual filenames, you need something like a for loop to handle the that manipulation on a per-filename basis.

Does this help?

**UPDATE:**

To put `_trim` before the extension, replace the `seqtk` line with the following:

```
    seqtk trimfq -b 10 -e 20 "$file" > "${file%.fastq}_trim.fastq"
```

This uses something documented in the Bash man page under `Parameter Expansion` if you want to read up on it.  Basically, the `${file%.fastq}` takes the `$file` variable and strips off a suffix.  Then we add your extra text, along with the suffix.

You could also strip an extension using [`basename(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=basename), but there's no need to call something external when you can use something built in to the shell.

Comment: I had thought I might have to do something like this. Just to clarify, does the array contain variables named seq as used in the for loop?

Would the array have to be defined explicity for each filename? As in an ideal world I was aiming to come up with some code I can just point at a folder and it takes the contents and performs the various actions I require.

Also, I presume the @ in the for loop is standing in place of the exact array contents but could you elaborate on what it does exactly - along with the need to switch to curly braces?

Comment: Sorry for the double post, but my first comment is still relevant. I modified the loop to the following:

     #!/bin/bash

     sequences=(*R1_001* *R2_001*)

     for seq in ${sequences[@]}; do

 for file in ${seq}; do
  seqtk trimfq -b 20 -e 20 "$file" > "trim_${file}"
      done
     done

Comment: The first for loop steps through each item in the array and assigns its value to `$seq`.  Since you have multiple files for each sequence, the second for loop steps through those files, running `seqtk` on each one individually.  The `@` in the first for loop is a bash-ism that expands the array.  You specified "bash" in your question rather than "shell", so I figured you didn't require an agnostic or portable solution. You can read about bash arrays [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) and [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).

Comment: For your modifications, perhaps you could [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23953504/edit), as comments really suck for formatting...

Comment: Yeah thank you very much ghoti, I didn't realise it wouldn't display in the comments, I thought I had edited it to delete that comment. I think I have the ideal code now so thank you for that and for the links to resources, I will certainly check those out. Can't rep you till I have 15 myself unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting variables with the filenames, you could pipe the output of `ls` to the command you want to run with these filenames, like this:

```
ls *R{1,2}_001* | xargs -I@ sh -c 'seqtk trimfq -b 10 -e 20 "$1" > "${1}_trim"' -- @
```

`xargs -I@` will grab the output of the previous command and store it in `@` to be used by `seqtk`

Comment: Yes, but keeping http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls in mind, you may want to prefer `echo` over `ls` so that you use the glob more directly. In difficult cases, I even prefer `find -print0 | xargs -0` so that spaces in filenames etc. don't trip up them `xargs`. :-)